# Bind click event for parent using child element's id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, event-delegation

I want to bind a click event on parent element using child element's id.

**I have this:**

```
<span class='k-link'> 
   <div id='myDiv'> </div>
</span>

<span class='k-link'> 
   <div id='myDiv2'> </div>
</span>
```

**I want to do this:**

```
$("#myDiv:parent").click(function() { });   //Does not work as expected
$("#myDiv2:parent").click(function() { });   //Does not work as expected
```

However, this does not result in the desired behavior, and the click event only works when clicked on myDiv and not on span.
I have no control over span, I can only give id to the div, how can I bind a click event for the myDiv's parent (which is a span tag).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method like following.

```js
$("#myDiv").parent().click(function() {
    alert('OK');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='k-link'> 
   <div id='myDiv'>DIV</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. However can you tell me why :parent does not work?

Comment: Actually I don't know what the problem is.  Once I had the same problem and solved like this. @zeppelin